# adding two different function on one plot

Tags: matlab

How can I add two different built-in Matlab functions on one plot? I have these two which work fine separately.

I know that both of the codes using `L` for their function so I've changed both of them to `R` and `F` and then `L=F+R` but it didn't work.

```
R = 1000.0;
freq = [15:5:1000]*1e9;
T = 20.0;
lwd = 0.5;
F = fogpl(R,freq,T,lwd);

freq = [1:1000]*1e9; 
RR=[0.75,1.75,2.5,3];

for irr=1:length(RR)
    R = rainpl(10000,freq,RR(irr));

    L=R+F;

    loglog(freq/1e9,L);
    hold on;

    grid
    title('rain attenuation')
    xlabel('Frequency (GHz)') 
    ylabel('Attenuation (dB)') 

end
```

The error in what I've tried only showed the line of `L=R+F`

```
"Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Untitled (line 22)
L=R+F;"
```

Comment: You redefine your `freq` vector, so `R` and `F` have different sizes and thus cannot be summed. If you evaluate them both for the same `freq` vector, you can sum them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that the sizes of the vectors you want to add are not the same. You need to change `freq`. According to the docs, `fogpl` needs `freq` to be in the range of 10GHz-1000GHz. So the following code will work:

```
R = 1000.0;
freq = [10:1000]*1e9;
T = 20.0;
lwd = 0.5;
F = fogpl(R,freq,T,lwd);

% freq = [10:1000]*1e9;
RR=[0.75,1.75,2.5,3];

for irr=1:length(RR)
    R = rainpl(10000,freq,RR(irr));

    L=R+F;
    loglog(freq/1e9,L);
    hold on;
end
grid on
title('rain attenuation')
xlabel('Frequency (GHz)')
ylabel('Attenuation (dB)')
```

Also the labeling of the axes and the title doesn't need to be called in every iteration, so it was moved outside of the loop.

[image: Desired image]

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Yes it was OPs code, but still thanks for the input, I edited the post.